# Russia could expect to capture

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Suppose that under the current balance of power, ***Russia could expect to capture*** this portion of Ukrainian territory in a war. Everything to the left stays Ukraine. And everything to the right goes to Russia.

Source: What Caused War between Russia and Ukraine NATO and Preventive Action Explained - YouTube

---

I'd like to know if the bold part is the same as "Russia could expect that Russia would capture".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **Russia could expect to capture** and **Russia could expect that Russia would capture** have the same meaning, but you'd almost never use the latter, since it sounds awkward and wordy. In English it's quite rare to repeat a noun that is the subject of a sentence, you'd almost always use a pronoun or, if appropriate, omit it.

**Russia could expect that it would capture** sounds natural, while **Russia could expect that Russia would capture** does not.